# How to I remove the huge space between my elements?

Tags: html, css

I am currently in a situation where I need a piece of text to be 158px, but that leaves a huge space between the 58px text directly below it. You can see it at [ktrn.pe.hu](http://ktrn.pe.hu/)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: please add your codes

Comment: Please show your codes.

Answer (score 2):

You can either decrease the `margin-bottom` or the larger text or decrease the `margin-top` of the smaller text.

Comment: Thank you! This worked the best out of all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't use the css reset your styleSheet , thats why you got the default padding and margin , just use this css on top of your stylesheet , if you dont use this you need to remove margin and padding all of the tags in your html page

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```